# Why can't I call this SDL2_gfxPrimitives function?

Tags: c, gcc, sdl-2

I have no trouble using the SDL2 library to launch a window and draw a colored square on a black background. But when I try using the SDL2_gfx library to draw a circle the filledCircleColor() is undefined:

```
make build;
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mike/compile/sdlTest'
gcc -std=c99 -c sdlTest.c;
gcc sdlTest.o -o sdlTest -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2;
sdlTest.o: In function `main':
sdlTest.c:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `filledCircleColor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [build] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mike/compile/sdlTest'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>


SDL_Event event;

//SDL2 variables
void* nullptr;
SDL_Window *win;
SDL_Renderer *ren;

int main(void) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        printf("SDL_Init Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    win = SDL_CreateWindow("sdlTest", 100, 100, 10*32, 10*32, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == nullptr) {
        printf("SDL_CreateWindow Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (ren == nullptr) {
        printf("SDL_CreateRenderer Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);


    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = 20;
    rect.y = 20;
    rect.w = 10;
    rect.h = 10;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 0, 0, 255, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(ren, &rect);


    filledCircleColor(ren, 50, 50, 50, 0xFF0000FF);

    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

    while(1) { ; }
}
```

Here's my Makefile:

```
test:
    make build;
    make run;

build:
    gcc -std=c99 -c sdlTest.c;
    gcc sdlTest.o -o sdlTest -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lSDL2;

run:
    ./sdlTest;

clean:
    -rm sdlTest;
    -rm *.o;
    -rm *~
```

I'm on a Linux box. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe link -lSDL_gfx? Not sure but looks like your not linking the library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the linker, that you are using `SDL2_gfx` extensions by adding `-lSDL2_gfx` options:

```
gcc sdlTest.o -o sdlTest -lSDL2 -lSDL2_gfx;
```

Note that `-I` flag is superfluous here, because you are at linkage stage.